# When should an embedded question take と?

Tags: grammar, particle-と, questions, particle-か

[From this article:](http://www3.nhk.or.jp/news/easy/k10011094771000/k10011094771000.html)

> ＮＨＫは６月〜７月、１８歳と１９歳の人に平和についてどう考えているか(*)聞きました。
>   Between June and July NHK asked 18 and 19 year olds what they thought about peace.
>   この日を知っているか**と**聞くと、...
>   When they were asked if they knew this date ...

I don't understand why と is absent in the place I marked (*) in the first sentence, but is required in the second sentence.

I thought I was happy with the idea of embedded questions with verbs like 知る that don't use と, but I'm a bit confused about when I should use と with verbs where it can be used.

How would the meanings of both sentences change with and without と?

Comment: my gut feeling is that it's a difference between a direct quote or not. 平和についてどう考えているか is probably a summary of the actual question not the question itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version without と only functions as a **kind of** <s>direct</s> indirect quote, as the comment says. On the other hand, the one with と can be either direct or indirect.

In this specific example, both seem an indirect quote. In that sense, it doesn't change either way.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand, but your answer seems to contradict itself. You say that the version **without** と can only be **direct**, but then say that both sentences seem to be **indirect**. Could you please clarify? Thanks.

Comment: Oops, you're right.